# Explode string to get keywords (Youtube channel keywords)

Tags: php, youtube

I am developing an application which requires the youtube api.

I am stuck at a point where i need the keywords of a youtube channel. I am getting all keywords in a string.

```
$string = 'php java "john smith" plugins';
```

I am trying to get the above keywords in an array. I can use `explode(' ',$string)` but the problem is `john smith` itself is a keyword. I am expecting my array to be like this:

```
array(
   [0] => 'php',
   [1] => 'java',
   [2] => 'john smith',
   [3] => 'plugins'
)
```

Any quick/dirty solution to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) will handle it, just give it a space as the delimiter.

#### Example:

```
$string = 'php java "john smith" plugins';
$array = str_getcsv($string, ' ');
var_export($array);
```

#### Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'php',
  1 => 'java',
  2 => 'john smith',
  3 => 'plugins',
)
```

Comment: Wow. Learnt something new today. Brilliant @Paul! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can try using `preg_replace()` to replace all inside double quotes. Before do it get all quoted strings in another array using `preg_match_all()`. Finally `array_merge()`

```
$string = 'php java "john smith" plugins';
$pattern = '/"(.*?)"/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $quotes_str);
$string = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);

$arr = array_filter(explode(' ', $string));
$arr = array_merge($arr, $quotes_str[1]);
```

Or can use `str_getcsv()`.

```
$arr = str_getcsv($string, ' ');

print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: Appologies, for not ticking your answer. Both you and Paul replied almost at the same time. I ticked Pauls answer just to boost his reputation by few inches.